# Jenkins rest api access using user specific apiToken

Tags: java, jenkins

Currently I'm using Jenkins 1.437 in our project. But the problem is when i am trying to access the jenkins build api with username and user specific api token I am getting 403 forbidden exception.

Could you please some one elaborate the apitoken user mechanism with the job token which will be put inside httpPost.